# What is the easiest and cheapest way to invest to HY corp bonds?

Tags: investing, debt, corporate-bonds

I would like to invest in high yield US debt. Picking companies with that rating sounds very involved and I don't have the knowledge for it. Do I buy index or ETF instead? Or what is the easiest and cheapest way to invest to HY corp bonds? And In the latter that would be a liquid investment, correct? I can always sell those shares and get my money back? And if there are coupons in those bonds they are usually just reinvested into index/etf and I don't get any intermediate CFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I buy index or ETF instead?

A High-Yield ETF would be a better use of risk since you spread the risk of default (which is not insignificant in high-yield debt) across many companies. Even if you buy
10 corporate bonds, if one of them defaults you've lost 10% of your investment.

> And In the latter that would be a liquid investment, correct?

Correct. ETFs are more liquid than individual corporate bonds.

> I can always sell those shares and get my money back?

Well, you can sell the shares for *what they're currently worth*, which might be less than what you paid for them. It's the same with individual bonds. You are only guaranteed to get the face value if you hold them to maturity. If you sell it before that you might have to sell for less than you paid for them.

> And if there are coupons in those bonds they are usually just reinvested into index/etf and I don't get any intermediate CFs?

The ETF gets the coupons, but high-yield bond ETFs typically pay dividends and capital gains from the ETF as well, so it depends on the payout structure of the ETF. Look at the "dividend" history of the ETF to see what it typically pays out.

Comment: so the ETF price stays fairly constant over time the way bond prices do(or in a range)? It is not like a stock keeps going up over the time? As all the benefit will be paid out as a dividend and not as price appreciation? In summary, it is similar to holding a bond where you get fixed cash flows every so often but they would be more sizable compare to stock dividends, and with stock I have a benefit of price appreciation.

Comment: @Medan no, the price of the ETF will go up and down as interest rates change, but so would the _value_ of a bond that you hold. If you hold it to maturity, you will get the full value back, but if you tried to sell it, it might be worth less than what you paid for it. They won't be as volatile as stocks, but they will fluctuate.